# Android SharedPreferences empty on Activity oncreate

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have declared the following Receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.ReferralReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

ReferralReceiver stores the referral values (utm_*) to the SharedPreferences object

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences storage = context.getSharedPreferences("ReferralParamsFile", 0);
    Editor editor = storage.edit();
    editor.putString("test", "test");
    editor.commit();
}
```

However when the main activity is created the SharedPreferences object is emtpy.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
SharedPreferences storage = context.getSharedPreferences(ReferralReceiver.PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String,String> referralParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
for(String key : ReferralReceiver.EXPECTED_PARAMETERS)
        {
            String value = storage.getString(key, null);
            if(value != null)
            {
                params.put(key, value);
            }
        }
}
```

I created a method to manually retrieve the SharedPreferences object after the creation of the activity and this seems to work fine. Any clues what could be wrong here and the initial call to the SharedPreferences object is empty?

Comment: Is there any chance that the Activity onCreate method is called before the onReceive method of the Referral Receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified from device logs that code in the "onCreate" method is called before the Broadcast Receiver updates the SharedPreferences object.

Comment: Where did you decide to call the SharedPreferences?

Comment: On the onReceive method of the ReferralReceiver that is configured in the AndroidManifest.xml file (to insert values in the SharedPreferences object)

Comment: But when do you read from the shared preferences now, if its not available during the onCreate?